# Get best table row for some specific condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to determine the best table row where a package with a certain height (for example 40cm, 77cm, 25cm) fits in.
Is it generally possible to evaluate something like this in SQL?

Example:
A package with 40cm height fits best in level 1
A package with 77cm height fits best in level 3

There is no package higher than 99cm.

My layer table is quite simple:

```
CREATE TABLE `levels` (
 `hall` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 `row` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
 `level` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `height` float(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `levels` (`hall`, `row`, `level`, `height`) 
VALUES ('D', '01', 0, 76.00),
       ('D', '01', 1, 41.00),
       ('D', '01', 2, 41.50),
       ('D', '01', 3, 100.00);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eWe8EEvWCpWtjiBA7cKzVW/1

Comment: Please share more details. How do you determine "best"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the condition in the `WHERE` clause and take the 1st row with the min height:

```
SELECT * 
FROM levels
WHERE height >= ? -- or maybe height > ?
ORDER BY height LIMIT 1;
```

Replace `?` with the height that you search for.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eWe8EEvWCpWtjiBA7cKzVW/2).

Answer (score 1):

Select the lowest fitting height and see which level it belongs to (replace 77 with the height you want to check):

```
SELECT `level`
FROM `levels`
WHERE `height` = (SELECT MIN(`height`) FROM `levels` WHERE `height` >= 77);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it